# sendResponse in chrome.runtime.onMessage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method: "getComments"
}, function(response) {
    var comments = response.arr;  //response is undefined
    ...
});
```

background page

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method === "getComments")
  chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true,
    'lastFocusedWindow': true
  }, function(tabs) {
    var serverUrl = newServerUrl + '?domain=' + tabs[0].url;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", serverUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.onload = ()=> {
      sendResponse({arr: 'something'});  //it seems this is not working
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
```

I'm trying to get the address of current tab using background page, send the address to a server to retrieve data, and pass the retrieved data back to content script. But sendResponse doesn't return anything to the content script. I'm developing a chrome extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having read the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

So, in the case of `getComments` you need to `return true`, as follows

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method === "getComments") {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            'active': true,
            'lastFocusedWindow': true
        }, function(tabs) {
            var serverUrl = newServerUrl + '?domain=' + tabs[0].url;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", serverUrl);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = () => {
                sendResponse({
                    arr: 'something'
                }); //it seems this is not working
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```